# ImageQuality with CGContextSetInterpolationQuality

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

How effective is the `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality` method in Quartz?

Does it affect the quality of the image? If so, to what extent?

I can't see any difference between the interpolated and the non-interpolated image.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Although this is a bit of an old question, I have recently done some benchmarking about the effects of `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality` and thought that its outcomes might be of interest to someone else.

In my benchmark test, I draw a set of 6 different 649x649 b&w bitmap images to build a set of 12 different jigsaw puzzle tiles. The bitmap images are scaled down by a factor of 5.0 (i.e., to 129.8x129.8) to make them fit on a 320x480 display (at retina display scale).

Run times on a 4th gen iPod touch, as reported by Instruments, are the following:

- kCGInterpolationLow:     969 msec
- kCGInterpolationMedium:  1690 msec
- kCGInterpolationHigh:    2694 msec
- kCGInterpolationNone:    545 msec

As to the visual outcome, if you compare High or Medium to Low or None, the difference is staggering. Even noticeable, IMO, the difference between None and Low; while the difference between High and Medium is not particularly noticeable in this particular test. What is clear is the difference in run times, so that in my particular case, I ended up using `kCGInterpolationMedium`.

**kCGInterpolationNone**

[image]

**kCGInterpolationLow**

[image]

**kCGInterpolationMedium**

[image]

**kCGInterpolationHigh**

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `kCGInterpolationHigh` as it was for magazine. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The method

`void CGContextSetInterpolationQuality ( CGContextRef c, CGInterpolationQuality quality );`

affect the way Quartz renders an image into a `CGContext`. This e.g. comes into play when the source image is larger or smaller than the target bitmap `CGContext`.

To exactly answer your question of why you don't see any noticable difference, I will need more details about the exact usage, image sizes, context types, etc.

Exactly what interpolation methods the different quality levels cover seems undocumented. A guess from my side would however be:

- Low:    Nearest neighbor interpolation
- Medium: Linear or bilinear interpolation
- High:   Quadratic or bicubic interpolation

Regards

Comment: but which is `kCGInterpolationNone`? I think it should be nearest neighbor